# Actionscript 3 Package/Constructors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've written a small game in AS3.0 where all the source files were in the root directory, no package organization whatsoever; mainly because it was a spur of the moment thing.  I've since moved everything into a proper package structure so I can organize, maintain, and continue to expand.

The problem with this move is that nothing works anymore.  I continuously get an "1136 : Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 0" error on the majority of my constructors.  All the package declarations look fine... besides it would tell me if it couldn't find a class.  Also, the errors seem to be happening on classes that are linked to movieclips.

I started to think that passing arguments to a linked class isn't allowed, but then again it works well when all the source is in one location.  Anyhow I tried using a no argument constructor and creating convenience methods/functions for the values I need to set quickly... now it doesn't understand my convenience function!?

Can someone shed some light please.

Sincerely frustrated,

Comment: When you moved your code into classes/packages you took the objects that the code controls out of scope. As for your 1136 error it sounds like you set your class/package up wrong you probably are getting "expected 0" because when you instantiate your class your are passing parameters to it. If I could suggest you might want to read up on class structures and good OOP methods before you go farther.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind... Another one of those silly errors that can keep a dev stuck for days.  I forgot to update the linkage to contain the new package name :P